# Set navigation bar hidden, depending on how the view controller appeared

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with a navigation controller in one of the tabs. Currently the root view of the navigation controller doesnt have the nav bar showing and animates nicely into the subviews by

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   ...
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
   ...
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

But of course changing tabs initiates the `viewWillAppear` function and so as I go back to the root view the navigation bar slides away, rather than just not being there.

Is there a way that I can hide the nav bar on the root view without animating it except for  when appearing from a subview on the navigation stack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `(BOOL)animated` parameter on `viewWillAppear:animated`. When changing Tabs, it will come as `NO`, since the animation is immediate. On the other hand, if it's being *pushed* or *popped* from the navigation stack with `animated:YES`, then it will come as `YES`.

Although this looks like a hack, it's the correct way: you don't need to figure out who was the caller, instead, focus on the fact that **if your view controller will appear animated, you have time to do your own animations**, if not, screw it, show (or in this case, hide) everything immediately.

Comment: This seems a bit breackable. What if tab switching behavior changes? How about
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:(self.navigationController.viewControllers.count>1) animated:YES];
}

Comment: @MihaiTimar thanks for the comment. Yes, that's a way to figure out who's the caller, and I encourage you to create a new reply to the original question with that. My answer focuses more on the fact that the `animated:(BOOL)` is useful more as a "Do I have time to do my own animation?" rather than trying to figure out how the view appeared. I updated my answer to make sure it comes clear.

Answer (score 3):

Try showing/hiding the bar in the UINavigationController's delegate's [navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController%3awillShowViewController%3aanimated%3a) method, depending on whether the view controller being shown is your root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set a boolean variable in your application delegate and in set that boolean accordingly in subviews as 0 and in other views as 1. And in your viewwillappear, according to your variable's value, you can set the animation.

Comment: it turns out that the animated boolean variable has solved the problem. thanks though.