# Popping View Controller causes Bar Button Item to disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two **ViewControllers** in my app. The first **ViewController** *(say, **ViewControllerOne**)* has a Bar Button Item that has a slide in **TableView** *(irrelevant to the question)*. I have disabled the **Navigation Bar** in the second ViewController *(say, **ViewControllerTwo**)* and added a custom view and a Button. I have written the code to pop ViewControllerTwo in thee action of the button. But once it is popped, the **BarButton** Item in **ViewControllerOne** disappears.
here is the code I have written in **ViewControllerTwo**

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

And

```
- (IBAction)backCustom:(id)sender 
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Any idea why the Bar Button Item would disappear because of this? I am sure this code is the reason because, When I remove it, it runs fine with the default **NavigationBar**.But I need a custom one for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first Viewcontroller add the following line

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: in each view controller handle this if you want the navigation bar

Comment: Why exactly does the navigation bar of a previous ViewController disappear when i have coded in the "hide" part in the current viewController?

Comment: The `(BOOL)animated` parameter on `viewWillAppear:animated`. When changing Tabs, it will come as `NO`, since the animation is immediate. On the other hand, if it's being *pushed* or *popped* from the navigation stack with `animated:YES`, then it will come as `YES`.

Although this looks like a hack, it's the correct way: you don't need to figure out who was the caller, instead, focus on the fact that **if your view controller will appear animated, you have time to do your own animations**, if not, screw it, show (or in this case, hide) everything immediately.

Comment: for quick answer I taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107503/set-navigation-bar-hidden-depending-on-how-the-view-controller-appeared