# Navigation bar doesn't appear using show (push) segue in iOS7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have three devices with three iOS version. I hide the navigation bar in `RootViewController`. Then for each `ViewController`, I display the navigation bar as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.text = @"Update Height";
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}
```

It works on two devices with iOS8.4 and iOS9.1, but not for iOS7.1. For the iOS7.1 device, if I change the segue to custom type, the navigation bar is displayed. But if I change to Show (Push) segue, the navigation bar doesn't show up.
What could be the problem?
I used segue from UIStoryBoard.
Thanks

Comment: r u sure the navigation bar is not made hidden on storyboard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107503/set-navigation-bar-hidden-depending-on-how-the-view-controller-appeared) and then try this

```
 //hide on current view controller
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

// show on next view controller
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i tried. It is still the same. Still hidden. All other devices work, only the device with iOS7.1 doesn't work.

Comment: then implemnt like above functionality worked fine on more than 5 projects for me , and if u like do as remove the hidden functionality from appdelegate and add view controller based navigation controller hiiden, surely works

Comment: else another one option ,  try in another one in iOS 7 based

Comment: I notice that if the next ViewController popup from the right side, the navigation bar still appears, but once the next View popup from the bottom, the navigation bar doesn't appear. What is the difference, the ViewController popup from the side and bottom.

Comment: **right side** means your navigation is **push**, **bottom** means your navigation in **Present** in here in your Navigation bar does not show, A navigation controller's navigation bar will only show up for view controllers that are contained by that navigation controller.  Here, you're presenting a modal view.  It's not contained by the navigation controller.

Comment: When you open a window modally whether it is Navigation Contoller or any other it will not show Back button, you will have to set it manually

Comment: So I tested embedded into the navigation controller. But when i press back button,  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; doesn't popup the previous view controller.

Comment: Now it works, I have to embed the calling ViewController into the NavigationController, then all work. Thanks

Comment: thanks man have a nice & good day , if my answer is hopeful give a upvote for the answer